# Objective C predicate that contains a String Within a String

Tags: string, nspredicate

So I have an nspredicate that I am using to filter values in a json array.  A sample of the code from the array that I am predicating is `"Drive Type" = AWD;`.

This is my current Predicate:

```
NSPredicate *Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"\"Drive Type\" CONTAINS %@", @"AWD"];
DriveTypeArray1 = [TransmissionArray1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:Predicate];
NSLog(@"drivetypearray%@", DriveTypeArray1);
```

This process has working for several other values but my "Drive Type" value is 2 words so it is in quotes.  I tried using escape sequences to get around this but the array always comes back empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `%K` format specifier for keys (or key paths) in predicate strings.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K CONTAINS %@", @"Drive Type", @"AWD"];
```